# How to test python local variables?

Tags: python, mocking, python-mock

So I have a monitor function that looks like:

```
def task1:
    // do some dummy work1
def task2:
    // do some dummy work2
def monitor:
  tasks = [task1, task2]
  while(true):
    sleep(1000)
    for task in tasks:
      task.run()
    if task1.alreadyRun():
       tasks.remove(task1)
```

I am wondering if there's way to do unit test by using some mock framework? Basically I want to make sure task1 was removed from the tasks list after it has been ran. However, I can't seem to figure out how to access local variables ie tasks here to determine its size in a mock framework. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Just my thoughts, if you absolutely need to inspect a functions local memory to verify that it has the correct result, then how could an "incorrect" result possibly affect anything else in the program? (Unless those other parts are already inspecting the functions local memory, in which case you wouldn't need to ask this question)

Comment: @HymnsForDisco Thanks for the reply. So the task1 is supposed to kill some old process. Task2 is starting new process if no new process has started. If task1 is not properly removed due to some bug then it may cause certain process to keep getting restarted.

Comment: my idea would be to pass the `tasks` list as a parameter to the monitor function.  This way you can maintain a reference to it without peeking into the functions local memory

Comment: @HymnsForDisco Ideally I don't want to change the function I am testing simply for testing purpose.

Comment: In that case you could have `monitor` internally maintain a timeout for `task1`, and raise a `RuntimeError` if the timeout duration is exceeded.  That is also changing the function, but only internally and making it more perhaps more expressive of the intended program behaviour